# How to change SwiftUI's Slider value from Swift code

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two published property called `sliderMinValue` and `sliderMaxValue`. These value are varied in a class called GameViewController.

GameViewController:

```
import Cocoa

class GameViewController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
        
    @Published var sliderMinValue: Double = 0.0
    @Published var sliderMaxValue: Double = 1.0
    
    ...
    
    sliderMinValue and sliderMaxValue are changed in this class...
    
    ...
    
}
```

I can pass these 2 value to SwiftUI Slider via GameView below.

GameView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameView: View {

@ObservedObject var gameViewController = GameViewController()

var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            ZStack {
                
                GoBan19View()
                StoneMapView()
            }
            
            SliderView()
            
        }.environmentObject(gameViewController)
    }
}
```

Here's my SliderView.

SliderView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SliderView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var gameViewController: GameViewController

    @State private var sliderVal: Double = 0
    @State var changing = false
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // For debug
            Text(String(gameViewController.sliderMinValue))
            Text(String(gameViewController.sliderMaxValue))
            
            Slider(value: $sliderVal,
                   in: gameViewController.sliderMinValue...gameViewController.sliderMaxValue,
                   step: 1,
                   onEditingChanged: { change in
                                        
                        self.changing = change
                
            })
            .padding()
            Text("CurrentValue：\(sliderVal)")
            Text(changing ? "Changing" : "Stopping")
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that `sliiderVal` can be changed via swift code or not. If it can, I'd like to set the `sliiderVal` to `gameViewController.sliderMaxValue`. In StoryBoard's slider, I can set the slider value like the code, `self.horizontalSlider.floatValue = Float(self.horizontalSlider.maxValue)`

Comment: Just set `sliderVal`? What didn't work?

Comment: What is wrong with `$gameViewController.sliderMaxValue`

Comment: Observations: use `@StateObject var gameViewController = GameViewController()`. You say, 
"...I'd like to set the sliderVal to gameViewController.sliderMaxValue", in that case, add `.onAppear {  sliderVal = gameViewController.sliderMaxValue }` to the `SliderView` `VStack`. Maybe your `GameViewController` should also include 
a `@Published var sliderValue: Double = 1.0`, because at the moment, you are not doing anything with `sliderVal` in `SliderView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example code that shows how you can `observe` the value in the slider,
using your `GameViewController` construct. That also means you can change
that value (sliderValue) anywhere in
your code and it will be reflected in the `Slider`.

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI


class GameViewController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var sliderMinValue: Double = 0.0
    @Published var sliderMaxValue: Double = 123.0  // <-- for testing
    
    @Published var sliderValue: Double = 0.0  // <--- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    
    @StateObject var gameViewController = GameViewController()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            //            ZStack {
            //                GoBan19View()
            //                StoneMapView()
            //            }
            SliderView()
        }.environmentObject(gameViewController)
    }
}

struct SliderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var gameViewController: GameViewController
    @State var changing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(gameViewController.sliderMinValue))
            Text(String(gameViewController.sliderMaxValue))
            Text("\(gameViewController.sliderValue)") // <--- here
            
            Slider(value: $gameViewController.sliderValue,  // <--- here
                   in: gameViewController.sliderMinValue...gameViewController.sliderMaxValue,
                   step: 1,
                   onEditingChanged: { change in
                self.changing = change
            })
            .padding()
            Text("CurrentValue：\(gameViewController.sliderValue)") // <--- here
            Text(changing ? "Changing" : "Stopping")
        }
    }
}
```